# POWERSHELL: Leer dos archivos

Tags: windows, powershell

Quisiera un script para crear de manera masiva correos en Exchange.

El nombre del buzon y AD me lo coge de 2 txt. No consigo hacerlo en un solo.

Por ejemplo:
Nombre.txt:

```
Buzon1
Buzon2
…
```

Alias.txt:

```
Buzon 1
Buzon 2
Buzon 3
```

Esto porque no consigo hacer que el PS lea todo de un unico fichero txt que seria lo mejor.

Mi código ahora mismo:

```
#Nombre del buzon 
$FILE = Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\name.txt"

##Nombre del buzon con espacios
$DN = Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\DN.txt"

foreach ($LINE in $FILE) {
foreach ($LINE0 in $DN) {

    ## Creamos usuario
    New-Mailbox -room -Name $Line -DisplayName $LINE0 -Alias $LINE -Database MLB220 

    
 }}
```